# jQuery Validation: Just English Characters + Just Numbers

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have input called "For", and another called "Item", I want to validate that text input for:
"For" -> English Characters + Digits.
"Item" -> Just English Characters.

```
$("#NewTransactionForm").validate({

    rules: {
        For: {
            required: true
        },
        Item: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

What do I need to add in "rules" section please?
I have googled it but didnt find solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your special validation rule using a regular expression.
To test your regular expression, [here is a tool](https://regex101.com/#javascript).

I found [many examples here](http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation/demo/), look at "Signin v4".

```
$("#NewTransactionForm").validate({

    rules: {
        For: {
            required: true,
            'LetterNumber': /^[a-z0-9]+$/gi
        },
        Item: {
            required: true,
            'Letter': /^[a-z]+$/gi
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'Letter': 'Only letters please.',
        'LetterNumber': 'Only letters and numbers please.',
        required: 'This field can't be empty.'
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited by adding the messages to be displayed for each rules.